# RxJs map operator to change the property value of a collection of objects in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my angular component I have the below properties:

```
memberInfoLists$: Observable<MemberInfo[]>;
total$: Observable<number>;
memberPhotoUrl: string = environment.memberPhotoUrl;
memberDefaultPhoto: string = environment.defaultPersonPhoto;
```

Now in **ngOnInit** function I have called the service to get the observable to fill **memberInfoLists$** property. But before the fill I want to change one of the property value of each object in the collection. Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.memberInfoLists$ = this.service.memberInfoLists$.pipe(map(item => item.forEach(y => {
            if (y.MemberPhotoUrl) {
                y.MemberPhotoUrl = this.memberPhotoUrl + y.MemberPhotoUrl;
            }   
            else{
                y.MemberPhotoUrl = this.memberDefaultPhoto;
            }   
            
            if (y.VoterPhotoUrl) {
                y.VoterPhotoUrl = this.memberPhotoUrl + y.VoterPhotoUrl;
            }   
            else{
                y.VoterPhotoUrl = this.memberDefaultPhoto;
            }   

            return item;
        })));
        this.total$ = this.service.total$;
    }
```

But it throws the below exceptions:

> src/app/setup-module/pages/member-info-list/member-info.component.ts:69:3
>
> - error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MemberInfo[]>'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type
>   'MemberInfo[]'.
>
>   this.memberInfoLists$ =
>   this.service.memberInfoLists$.pipe(map(item => item.forEach(y => {

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return statement is on wrong place it should be after forEach

and there should be curly brackets around forEach

```
this.memberInfoLists$ = this.service.memberInfoLists$.pipe(
      map((item) => {
        item.forEach((y) => {
          if (y.MemberPhotoUrl) {
            y.MemberPhotoUrl = this.memberPhotoUrl + y.MemberPhotoUrl;
          } else {
            y.MemberPhotoUrl = this.memberDefaultPhoto;
          }

          if (y.VoterPhotoUrl) {
            y.VoterPhotoUrl = this.memberPhotoUrl + y.VoterPhotoUrl;
          } else {
            y.VoterPhotoUrl = this.memberDefaultPhoto;
          }
        })
        return item;
      }
      )
    );
```